# Javascript json, check all keys for undefined ('null') and set default

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, null, undefined

Firstoff I'd like to add I've been learning javascript for like only 2 days now. I'm pretty much way ahead of myself with what I'm trying to get but here goes.

I have a json array from which I get data to replace/insert in my page. The first problem I have is that if it comes across an empty ('null') key it will just stop. Will not even try to continu.

```
document.getElementById("id1")src=json.img1.link;
document.getElementById("id2")src=json.img2.link;
document.getElementById("id3")src=json.img3.link;
```

json.img2.link is empty ('null' response from json.). javascript will then not replace "id2" but it also won't replace "id3".

I'm now trying to find a solution where it will if nothing else at least set a default.

Comment: Show a snippet of relevant JSON.

Comment: Note that "empty" and "null" aren't really the same thing in the JavaScript world, and neither are `undefined` and `null`. There's a difference between an object not having a property at all and having a property that has the value `null` or the value `undefined`. Note also - and please don't take this as a criticism, I know you're new to JS so I'm just trying to give you a heads up - that from the way you are using `json.img1.link` it would seem you have an _object,_ not an _array._  (Also, your `json` variable doesn't actually hold JSON: JSON is always a string but you have an object.)

Comment: it was actually document.getElementById("id2").src=json.img2.link+".jpg";  I just didn't write it in since that wasn't the problem. The issue is the "null" response from json. If I use a feed that gives me similar results, but not 'null' it will work. So the only issue is that I don't know how to handle the error. Allthough the best thing to do would be actually to specify a default in the src of the ID by itself and let javascript just ignore that like of code and move on. I've posted in a comment below a link to the page with the code in it.

Comment: Is it the `img2` property of `json` that is missing (or `null`), or the `link` property of `img2` that is missing? Can you show the actual JSON response in question? (Try `console.log(json)` with your browser's JS console open (F12 opens it in Chrome).)

Comment: the whole img2 is empty. But I didn't paste the exact code I shortened it and made it something people would actually understand. But here's the json response. A world of warcraft character feed. http://divium.eu/dreamweaver/encode.php?realm=haomarush&name=veider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script is not continuing executing because it comes to an error --trying to access property link of an undefined object

Try

`document.getElementById('id2').src = json.img2 ? json.img2.link : 'defaultLink';`

This way your are checking for `undefined` (ie null) object in img2 and assigning the default value. This assumes that what is not defined (null) is the img2 object.

Comment: Didn't work, but then again I might have done something wrong. You're free to look at the code at http://divium.eu/dreamweaver/index.html it stops on line 73 for this json feed http://divium.eu/dreamweaver/encode.php?realm=haomarush&name=veider also keep in mind I've been doing this for 2 days and php for 5 days so everything might be very messy for someone that know's what he's doing :)

Comment: From your link, if I click on the 'Fetch Armory' button, it says `validateName` is not defined... before it executes loadXMLDoc, are you sure this is the right code?

Comment: Yeah it's right. Fixed it now. Forgot about that. I decided to not check input but just deleted the function, forgot the trigger.

Comment: Now I get that data.status === "1" so it goes into the else part (line 103)

Comment: I think I just found my mistake. When making the json feed myself from different sources I didn't take into account, what if the original feed didn't even have the information I wanted. If you go here http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/character/haomarush/veider?fields=items you can see that the actual     'shirt' array is missing. That's one of the feeds I got information from to make my own feed. It doesn't give out a 'null' since it doesn't even exist in that feed.

Comment: Jaime, type Veider for name and Haomarush for Realm. The feed returns a     data.status 1 if it can't find what you're looking for.

Comment: So your problem is that `data.gear.shirt` is `null`, so you have to do the checking for at least that property (ie `document.getElementById("shirtL").href="http://www.wowhead.com/item="+ (data.gear.shirt ? data.gear.shirt.id : 'no-id-put-default-here');` but you should probably check for null on other properties too

Comment: Worked! Awesome stuff. Thanks Jaime! Now to bed, gonna fix the whole thing tomorrow. 5am here, thanks again and good night ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't think your code should work at all, you are missing the`.` before the `src` So, try

```
document.getElementById("id1").src=json.img1.link;
document.getElementById("id2").src=json.img2.link;
document.getElementById("id3").src=json.img3.link;
```

and let us know if that doesn't solve the problem.

Btw, +points for learning JavaScript and not just straight into jQuery!

Comment: That was a typo I made when writing the post and just copy pasted the line, my bad ^^